# Dockerfile Customization for Google Cloud Run with Nginx and uWSGI

Tags: django, docker, nginx, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to migrate a Django application from Google Kubernetes Engine to Google Cloud Run, which is fully managed. Basically, with Cloud Run, you containerize your application into a single `Dockerfile` and Google does the rest.

I have a `Dockerfile` which at one point does call a bash script via `ENTRYPOINT`

But I need to start Nginx and start Gunicorn. The Google Cloud Run documentation suggest starting Gunicorn like this:

`CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT foo.wsgi`

(let's sat my Django app is named "foo")

But I also need to start Nginx via:

`CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`

And since only one `CMD` is allowed per Dockerfile, I'm not sure how to combine them.

To try to get around some of these difficulties, I was looking into using a Dockerfile to build from that already has both working and I came across this one:
https://github.com/tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-docker

But the paths don't quite match mine. Quoting from the documentation of that repo:

> You don't need to clone the GitHub repo. You can use this image as a
>   base image for other images, using this in your `Dockerfile`:
>
> `FROM tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn:python3.7`
>
> `COPY ./app /app` It will expect a file at `/app/app/main.py`.
>
> And will expect it to contain a variable `app` with your "WSGI"
>   application.

My `wsgi.py` file ends up at `/app/foo/foo/wsgi.py` and contains an application named `application`

But if I understand that documentation correctly, when it says it will expect the WSGI application to be named app and to be located at `/app/app/main.py` it's basically saying that I need to revise the path and the variable name so that when it builds the image it knows that `app` is called `application` and that instead of finding it at `/app/app/main.py` it will find it at `/app/foo/foo/wsgi.py`

I assume that I can fix the `app` vs `application` variable name by adding a line to my `wsgi.py` file like `app = application` but I'm not sure how to correct the path that Docker expects.

Can someone explain to me how to adapt this to my needs?

(Or any other way to get it working)

Comment: Why do you need nginx here?

Comment: I was new to Kubrenetes and Docker when I started this project 6 months ago and I had found a containerized application that we wanted up and running, the developer build it with Nginx and uWGSI. Gunicorn seems easier to configure than uWSGI so I switched but left Nginx in place as it seemed advisable to have a traditional "server" to handle static assets and such...so short answer, it uses Nginx because the original developer built it that way I figured it needed it.

Comment: The rule of thumb is one process per container and you are proposing two (nginx and gunicorn) that do the same job here. 
If you post your configuration of Nginx and gunicorn we can help you drop Nginx.

Comment: For anyone that comes across this later: after reading these comments and experimenting with the suggestions (and even trying to implement 'init scripts' such as "dumb init"), I came to the conclusion that the application I wanted to run, and the outcomes I wanted, just weren't a good fit for Google Cloud Run...yes, it only charges you for cycles when the app is actively running (which was attractive) but from a 'cold start' it would have taken an unacceptably long time to run and users/bots making requests (there was an anonymous, public form) would cause the app to spin up add'l instances...

Comment: ...and I would end up paying for the processing on those additional instances. The uWSGI docs (v20.x) are very clear that uWSGI is highly vulnerable to DDoS attacks and they strongly suggest putting it behind a reverse proxy such as Nginx, so I decided that the 'cons' outweighed the 'pros' largely because any hacker or bot could submit the form and trigger my app to run--even if it took 90 seconds to complete, which most users would abandon. So, if your app requires background processes, or a snappy response, or can be publicly, anonymously triggered, you'd be wise to consider other options.